# Lambda function ellipsis (underscore in C#) equivalent in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

I have the following lambda function in C# which I want to migrate to VB.NET:

```
    private static void CreateAndVisualizeSensitiveFilteredFixationsStream()
    {
        _fixationDataStream = _host.Streams.CreateFixationDataStream();
        _fixationDataStream
            .Begin((x, y, _) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" +
                                      "Fixation started at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y);
                    _fixationBeginTime = DateTime.Now;
                })
            .Data((x, y, _) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("During fixation, currently at: X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y);
                })
            .End((x, y, _) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Fixation ended at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y);
                    if (_fixationBeginTime != default(DateTime))
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                        Console.WriteLine("Fixation duration: {0}", DateTime.Now - _fixationBeginTime);
                        Console.ForegroundColor = _defaultForegroundColor;
                    }
                });
    }
```

As one can see, the third argument of ".Begin(x, y, _)" is an ellipsis.

VB.NET won't accept this underscore. What would be the equivalent in VB.NET?

Here is my attempt of a conversion, I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but the underscore is very likely to be wrong in VB.NET, I guess. Thanks you.

```
    Private Shared Sub CreateAndVisualizeSensitiveFilteredFixationsStream()
        _fixationDataStream = _host.Streams.CreateFixationDataStream()
        _fixationDataStream.Begin(Function(x, y, _)
                                      Console.WriteLine(Constants.vbLf & "Fixation started at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
                                      _fixationBeginTime = DateTime.Now
               ).Data(Function(x, y, _ )
                    Console.WriteLine("During fixation, currently at: X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
               ).End(Function(x, y, _)
                    Console.WriteLine("Fixation ended at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
                                      If _fixationBeginTime IsNot Nothing Then
                                          Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
                                          Console.WriteLine("Fixation duration: {0}", DateTime.Now.Subtract(_fixationBeginTime))
                                          Console.ForegroundColor = _defaultForegroundColor
                                      End If
                                  End Function
               )
    End Sub
```

This is the Begin function:

```
public class FixationDataStream : DataStreamBase<FixationDataBehavior, FixationData>
{
    public FixationDataStream(FixationDataBehavior fixationDataBehavior, Action hasSubscribersChanged, bool enabled);

    public FixationDataStream Begin(Action<double, double, double> action);
    public FixationDataStream Data(Action<double, double, double> action);
    public FixationDataStream End(Action<double, double, double> action);
}
```

Comment: I don't know whether the underscore has a special meaning in VB.Net, but you could perhaps replace the underscore with a dummy variable name, i guess (like `Function(x,y,temp)`)

Comment: Thanks, but when I do this, I get a "Syntax error" message from the compiler in the line " ).Data(Function(x, y,temp)"

Comment: Okay, verify that `Function(...)` in VB.Net is actually the same as `Action<...>` in C#. I am not sure, but the equivalent to `Action<...>` could perhaps be `Sub(...)`

Comment: When I import the DLL into VB.NET, the object browser tells me the following: Public Function Begin(action As System.Action(Of Double, Double, Double)) As Tobii.Interaction.FixationDataStream
    Member von "Tobii.Interaction.FixationDataStream"

Comment: I guess there's just something else wrong about my transcription to VB.NET in the line ).Data(Function, but I don't see what it might be.

Comment: Yes, and... what should your last comment regarding the object browser tell me? (I am not sure what you try to tell me there...)

Comment: I tried a converter, and I found the culprit. The underscore was alright, but I forgot 2 "End Function" in my conversion. So I'm going to delete the question. Thank you very much anyways.

Comment: @tmighty: The underscore is definitely not alright.

Answer (score 0):

Those lambdas should be 'Sub' lambdas.  In addition, you are not closing most of them (with 'End Sub').  Also, you cannot use an underscore by itself as a variable name in VB:

```
    Private Shared Sub CreateAndVisualizeSensitiveFilteredFixationsStream()
        _fixationDataStream = _host.Streams.CreateFixationDataStream()
        _fixationDataStream.Begin(Sub(x, y, underscore)
                    Console.WriteLine(vbLf & "Fixation started at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
                    _fixationBeginTime = Date.Now
        End Sub).Data(Sub(x, y, underscore)
                    Console.WriteLine("During fixation, currently at: X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
        End Sub).End(Sub(x, y, underscore)
                    Console.WriteLine("Fixation ended at X: {0}, Y: {1}", x, y)
                    If _fixationBeginTime <> Date.MinValue Then
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan
                        Console.WriteLine("Fixation duration: {0}", Date.Now - _fixationBeginTime)
                        Console.ForegroundColor = _defaultForegroundColor
                    End If
        End Sub)
    End Sub
```

Comment: If you really want to, you could probably use a single underscore by escaping it i.e. `[_]`.

Comment: Interesting, I had thought that might give an anything-goes access to names, apparently not.  Maybe it just addresses reserved words that would otherwise be legal names?

Comment: Inside the square brackets, it still has to be a valid name.  The square brackets just ensures that it's not confused with a reserved word or an existing type.